# Separating Words in a List Tkinter Listbox Python

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, python-2.7

In my source code for a project I am running I have a process that produces a list of strings. I am trying to put this list into a Tkinter listbox for easy sorting, but when I do the list is all inserted into one line and I can't find a way to separate the individual words into a different line on the listbox. Any ideas I am open to anything. Below I have attach an example of what I am trying to do:

```
from Tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.geomtery("500x700")
app.title("ListBox")

names = ["Greg", "Earl", "Harry", "Bob"]

box = Listbox(app)
# Right here is where I am stuck
box.insert(END, names)
box.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very esay in python, no ?:
just add the item and not the list

```
# Right here is where I am stuck
for i in names:
    box.insert(END, i)
```

and

```
app.geometry("500x700")
```

Comment: I think that was pretty much what I said ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do it:

```
from Tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.geometry("500x700")
app.title("ListBox")

names = ["Greg", "Earl", "Harry", "Bob"]

box = Listbox(app)
# Right here is where I am stuck
for name in names:
    box.insert(END, name)

box.pack()
app.mainloop()
```